# Get the height and width of an image more efficiently

Tags: java, image, performance

I'm building a crawler and i need to get the height and the width of a remote image (or multiple images). I'm already doing that with threads - but still this is the task consuming most of the time:

```
//Start threadppol
            ExecutorService imageExecutorService = null;
            List<Future<ImageModel>> futureImages = null;
            if (imageSize > 0) {
                imageExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
                futureImages = new ArrayList<>();
                int counter=0;
                for (Image imgUrl : imgUrls) {
                    Callable<ImageModel> callable = new ExtractImages(imgUrl,hostUrl);
                    Future<ImageModel> future = imageExecutorService.submit(callable);
                    futureImages.add(future);
                    if(counter>=4){
                        break;
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
            }
```

ExtractImages class:

```
 // Get the image
 BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL(hostUrl, extractedImage.getSrc()));
```

So i'm using kind of the standard way to do it in Java (ImageIO.read(url)).
The question is, is there a better way to get the height and with of an image from an imageurl?

Comment: Has to be. If the image file didn't encode that somehow somewhere, how could it ever be re-created from data? That being said, I don't know anything on the specifics

Comment: Made an edit - hope i made it clearer. What i want is to retrieve the height and width of an image from an image url. ImageIO.read(url) is too slow - and this is probably because of the response time needed (from my application to the image host). But still - i would like to know if there is a better way.

Comment: So you want to get height and width of a remote image (remote resource)?

Comment: Exactly yes - but without reading inline styles (img src "" width=365).

Comment: The information you need is in the image header, so it's unnecessary to read the image data.  Check out `ImageReader.getImageMetadata()` or `ImageReader.getWidth/Height()`.

Comment: Ahh - sounds promising :) Will try that! Maybe write it as an answer so you get credit for it!